# How to coordinate two sessions writing the same row to a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6 and have an append-only "lookup" table that's used to store reference data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  my_column VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY my_column_uk (my_column)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Rows are inserted, but never updated or deleted. The table is small (thousands of rows at most), so query performance is not a concern.

I have 2 different processes (running identical code) which insert rows into this table. Each process has an in-memory write-through cache of the `my_column` -> `id` value. Whenever a new entry is put into the cache that doesn't already exist, it's synchronously inserted into the database table, then added to the cache.

**How do I handle the scenario where 2 (or more) processes try to insert the same `my_column` value at the same time?**

Since the table has a unique key constraint on `my_column`, my thought is to have both processes try to insert the new row and get the new PK `id` value. One of them will succeed, and can add the new entry to its cache. The other one will fail, but then it can fall back to querying for the `id` of the row that the *other* process inserted. I call this the "write-read" approach.

Is there a better way of handling this contention between the two processes? Would a "read-write" approach be better, potentially with a different transaction isolation level ("read uncommitted" e.g.)?

The one potential downside I see with the "write-read" approach is that it involves catching a duplicate key exception, and using that as an indicator to query for the existing row. This is perhaps a misuse of an exception, because this scenario is expected to occasionally happen, and is *not* really exceptional.

The problem with the "read-write" approach is that I'm not sure there's a good way to have process 2 "see" the row that process 1 added, until it finishes its transaction. So this might need to be a "read-write-read", in which case I'm better off just starting with the INSERT like in the "write-read" approach.

---

Some more constraints:

1. I need to get the resulting PK ID, regardless of whether the row was inserted or already exists. However I *don't* want to burn through auto-increment values, so I'm not going to use the `UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` kludge. I'd rather just execute a second SQL statement to SELECT the id value, because I'm only inserting a row every ~5 minutes into a table with ~100k rows, so query performance is not a major concern.
2. The reason why I'm not using the VARCHAR `my_column` column as the `PRIMARY KEY` column is that this lookup table has a FK reference from another much bigger (500M rows, 20 cols) table. I'm using this lookup table pattern to store reference data - e.g. failure codes ("eligibility.failure.not_enough_foobar_data") or time zones ("America/Los_Angeles") - so that the much larger main table can use a short FK id to reference that value (e.g. `failure_code_id` or `time_zone_id`), instead of repeating the long string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best solution I've been able to come up with, using a write-read approach:

1. INSERT using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE; (*without* first checking to see if the row exists)
2. if the value returned != 0, then that's the PK of the new row;
3. else a row must already exist with that value, so SELECT it;
4. if the SELECT can't find the row, then throw an exception because this is unrecoverable.

This has the following advantages:

1. it doesn't require any transactionality or a different isolation level, because the insert-if-not-exists statement is already an atomic operation;
2. it executes at most 2 SQL statements (insert-select) instead of 3 (select-insert-select), making the calling code simpler;
3. since we're *not* using INSERT IGNORE, if the INSERT statement throws an exception it will be for a legit reason - e.g. auto_increment has reached the max value of `id` column - and thus we don't have to worry about needlessly logging duplicate key exceptions or ignoring actual database problems.

Answer (score 1):

If both threads will insert *identical* values, use `INSERT IGNORE`.  If you need to get the resulting id, use the kludge of IODKU with `... UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`.  (It's in the manual.)

Keep in mind that both IODKU and `INSERT IGNORE` will 'burn' ids.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) for a way to avoid such.

Since you have a `UNIQUE` key, why not use it as the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Provide your argument for having both so I can argue against both (or agree that both makes sense).

**Addressing constraints**

1. In http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization , I discuss how to mass insert new rows without buring ids, then get the ids.  Yes, it takes 2 statements, but only 2 for any number of rows conditionally inserted.

The first statement is `INSERT ... SELECT ...` where the `SELECT returns only the number of rows needed -- 0 or more (up to 1 in your case).  That keeps the`INSERT`from wasting any ids.  The`SELECT`gets the`ids` for all rows (1 in your case).  Yes, it assumes the desired data has already been put into a "staging" table, so that makes it possibly too messy for your case.

2. If you are concerned about space, and `my_column` is something with a finite list of possibilities (eg, timezones), note that `INT` is 4 bytes.  Consider `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte, values 0..255) or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, values 0..64K).

Comment: Good follow-up questions, I will update my question to answer them!

Comment: I responded.....

Comment: Regarding point #1, can you compare the solution you've suggested at that URL to the IODKU approach that I provided in my answer below? I don't have a staging table, so I'm having a hard time contrasting your suggested approach to my IODKU + SELECT answer.

Comment: Regarding point #2, I completely agree. In my database, I actually have multiple lookup tables, all of which are designed and inserted in the same fashion as I described in this question. The `time_zone` table does in fact use a `TINYINT UNSIGNED` PK, whereas the `failure_reason` table uses a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`, and even larger lookup tables use a `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` PK.

Comment: OK, you are right about #1.